# Android xamarin app shows when screen is locked

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a cross-platform xamarin app, everything compiles and app works as it should.

Problem is with the behavior of the Android app.

1. I open app and use it, then press the power button to lock screen.
2. When I press the power button again it takes me back to the app and this is not normal or usual like any other app on the phone.
3. After pressing the power button it should show the locked screen so that I can swipe or enter my phone security pattern not take me directly to the app.

Any pointers or suggestion to overcome this behavior are welcome.

**UPDATE 1**

I've removed the following from my manifest but still the App over powers the screen lock

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

**UPDATE 2**
Current manifest
[image]

Comment: Maybe provide your entire Manifest file. And also try clrean\rebuild\uninstall after Manifest file changes.

Comment: What's the rest of your manifest file look like?

Comment: Can  you share a demo for that?

Comment: Post updated with the Manifest file...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, can you share a demo for that?